# Onclick a picture turns in to text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, onclick, image

I was wondering if anyone could help me. On the 'About Us' page there is a profile for each team members, below which is their email address. I would like for there to be a picture and when the picture is clicked for it disappear and for the team members email address in it's place.

The page is - http://www.thescribblingape.com/aboutus/

I do not have much experience of JavaScript or jQuery but I am guessing I can use them to do this.

I tried using;

```
<div id="email-button">

  <img class="email-button-image" onclick="this.style.display = 'none';" alt="Email" src="http://www.thescribblingape.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/tSA-Email-Button-post-150x150.png" width="150" height="150" />

   sam@thescribblingape.com

 </div>
```

CSS

```
#email-button {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here. If your website is changed, this question will not make sense.

Comment: Can you give us what you already wrote?

Comment: Java? You mean javascript. And provide relevant code here, this is quite a simple task you are asking

Comment: Hi Stuart, it seems like you want a "caption" of sorts. Chris Coyier has an excellent [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/slide-in-image-captions/) on the subject. If that's not what you want, i'd suggest searching for a few other examples, trying them out, and then refining your question here on SO.

Comment: @NickTomlin thanks for the link. Be useful for the future. But in this instance id like for the picture to disappear and at the same time the text to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relatively simple solution for your problem, albeit I've wrapped the text in an element to easily target it via CSS:

```
<div id="email-button">
    <img class="email-button-image" alt="Email" src="http://www.thescribblingape.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/tSA-Email-Button-post-150x150.png" width="150" height="150" />
    <p>sam@thescribblingape.com</p>
</div>
```

The following JavaScript would toggle between the `p` and the `img` being visible:

```
function toggle(el) {
    var img = el.getElementsByTagName('img'),
        p = el.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (var i = 0, len = img.length; i<len; i++){
        img[i].style.display = img[i].style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
    for (var i = 0, len = p.length; i<len; i++){
        p[i].style.display = p[i].style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
    }
}

var button = document.getElementById('email-button');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    toggle(button);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vb6nM/).

The above could be re-written with jQuery, to give:

```
$('#email-button').click(function () {
    $(this).find('img, p').toggle();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vb6nM/2/).

With some rewriting of your HTML, you could even do this with just HTML and CSS; the HTML being rewritten to:

```
<label for="toggle">
    <input id="toggle" type="checkbox" />
    <img class="email-button-image" alt="Email" src="http://www.thescribblingape.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/tSA-Email-Button-post-150x150.png" width="150" height="150" />
    <p>sam@thescribblingape.com</p>
</label>
```

And the CSS:

```
label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

label input {
    display: none;
}

label input + img,
label input:checked ~ p {
    display: block;
}

label input:checked + img,
label input ~ p {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vb6nM/3/).

Though this *does* require a fairly up-to-date browser, unfortunately.